# CakeDC(cakePHP) comments plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

First I will start with the fact that I am on a MAC.

I have git cloned the cakeDC comments plugin into my application Plugin directory.  Upon trying to execute the given commands to setup the database tables for this plugin I receive this error:

```
sudo Console/cake scheme create --plugin Comments --name app

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysqli.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysqli.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_openssl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_openssl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Error: Shell class SchemeShell could not be found.
#0 /Users/bellis/workspace/intranet/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(167): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('scheme')
#1 /Users/bellis/workspace/intranet/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#2 /Users/bellis/workspace/intranet/app/Console/cake.php(33): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#3 {main}
```

Why in the world is this command trying to use .dll files ( Windows Only ) on my MAC install.  Is there something I am missing here?  Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not running in safe mode are you?  Think you need to make sure PHP running as CLI is using the proper php.ini.

Comment: Looks like it initiates .dll just for support of windows users.  That is my assumption anyways.  I have figured out the issue.  I will post the answer when I can.

Comment: When you say "windows users" you mean clients running windows?  I must be misunderstanding, that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, clients running windows.  I found that removing the --name app from the console command created the necessary database table and columns for the plugin.  Although, in the terminal on my mac it still tries to use .dll files...seems odd.

sudo Console/cake scheme create --plugin Comments

Comment: So if you are baking this for a windows server and your remote machine is Ubuntu it checks that the .so's are installed on the windows server?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Shell class SchemeShell could not be found.
#0 C:\wamp\www\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(200): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('scheme')
#1 C:\wamp\www\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#2 C:\wamp\www\app\Console\cake.php(47): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#3 {main}
```

So I just spent about 15 minutes rifling through the stack trace trying to figure this out.  I couldn't find a *SchemeShell.php* file anywhere, but I did notice a *SchemaShell.php* in the *Cake/Console/Command* directory.  After looking around for awhile, I took a better look at the console command I was entering.

```
c:\wamp\www\app>Console\cake scheme create DbAcl
```

At this point I went palm to forehead and took a moment to laugh at myself.  I was trying to create a **schema** but telling Cake to make me a **scheme**, which obviously isn't going to work out too well for me.

> "Experience is simply the name we give our mistakes" -Oscar Wilde

Finally success...

```
c:\wamp\www\app>Console\cake schema create DbAcl

The following table(s) will be created.
acos
aros
aros_acos
Are you sure you want to create the table(s)? (y/n)
[y] > y
Creating table(s).
acos updated.
aros updated.
aros_acos updated.
End create.
```